# orphanRemoval does not work for entities with naturalId persisted via SpringData .save method

Tags: hibernate, jpa

UPDATE/TLDR: entity merged into persistence context does not correctly handle collection annotated with orphanRemoval.

minimalistic example is here: https://github.com/alfonz19/orphan-removal-test/tree/justMergeFlow

please see README.md for details.

---

ORIGINAL POST:

Spring has this save method

```
@Transactional
@Override
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null.");

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

which brings some convenient behavior, but it seems it can lead to surprising things, as orphan removal seems to be affected, if you initially created the entity via persist, merge or save. If you can comment on it, please do. I don't have minimal example yet, but I can theoretically create it.

discussed scenario:

1. you start with empty db, you have trivial 1:N association. It's just mapping some strings to entity, like if you'd like to avoid comma separated list.

non-owning side of association(the `1:`), has naturalID, and association is annotated as:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "xxx", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
```

owning side of association is annotated as following, and entity has composite natural pk:

```
@EmbeddedId
private PK pk;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "xxx", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private XXX xxx;
```

2. processing. Single transaction, you create entity in new state, add one association entity into list and *save* the entity (we will get back to *save* operation later). Now we remove that item from collection (removeIf given item / clear / whatever) and another one. TX commit.

Now what will be in the database after this? Well, I have 3 different results:

a.  If the initial *save* operation was entityManager.persist, the result is as I'd expect:  top-level record exist and has single associated item, the one we didn't remove in its association list. That's great.

b. If the initial *save* operation was entityManager.merge or SimpleJpaRepository#save (which will call merge, because of isNew behavior for naturalId entity; id != null --> it's detached allegedly), the entity will be also created, but modifications on list won't be persisted, meaning even though I can see, that before commit the target state of entity is the one described in variant a), the item which we removed from association will be persisted and the other one not. Ie. the state with which we called *save* will be inserted, further alterations on association list won't be reflected.

c. and every such issue won't be complete without bizarre case, and I'm glad I need not to disappoint you. When there are more operation in between all of this, but which are not touching these entities, probably some flush is induced, and in the end I'm left with both entities in association collection; meaning that the top-level entity must have been managed and changes to its association entities reflected, but somehow hibernate need not felt pressure to remove entity, which was removed from that collection.

The solution(or maybe workaround) is simple: just use persist if you know that you're persisting. Easy. Then it will just work without hiccup. And I think it's even correct move, personally I don't like the idea behind SimpleJpaRepository#save. But I feel I might be missing something, as this seems to be to dangerous to write *save* method, which will do persist or merge, if this is possible outcome. And I definitely don't see the reason for scenario b/c. Even if I use merge incorrectly here, the entity is managed after being brought to persistence context, and touching its association collection should be correctly handled, yet it's not.

Notes:

- Yes, everything is done in single tx.
- I checked whether every entity is and when in persistence context, and I didn't find any difference between persist/merge used as *save* method scenario. So I have no idea why there is different outcome.

Any idea what could I check more? Or even where my mistake is?

Comment: Save isn't a JPA construct - if it is Spring, and they inject their own logic into it overtop, like calling find and merge vs persist. What is important though is that you should be using the instance returned from the save operation for any further changes and updates. Your original instance might not reflect what is actually in the database, but the returned instance should - important if merge is used. Your reference you passed in isn't won't have values set, but the one returned will (when the transaction commits or is flushed anyway). So use the one returned from save in all cases.

Comment: @Chris well IIUC, and correct me if I'm wrong, spring just calls persist / merge on EntityManager. Accessing e.g. entityInformation probably does not alter persistence context. And persist/merge are side-effect functions, meaning, that what I passed into them gets updated. The functional feel of spring save method is just made via returning what was passed into them as parameter. So unless I'm really overlooking smth (please show me what and where!)  not using what was returned from spring save method should not be any problem.

Comment: Persist and merge are two very different api. Persist takes in what you pass it and makes it managed - which should explain what you've seen, as now the EntityManager context has a reference to it and any further changes made to the instance. Merge though takes what you give it and *merges* it into the EM context. What it returns is the managed instance it is tracking changes on - which is (unless you've called persist or find then merge on that instance) different from what you passed in. Method signatures return things because they are important, and the repo save method docs state this

Comment: Don't take my word for it - scope it out yourself in a debugger. Better yet, try it as you'll quickly see you are wrong. Merge/persist are not side effect functions - what you pass to them does NOT get updated in many many cases. If you call persist on a new entity, nothing within that entity instance has to change, or may change at all, until after the transaction commits (or is flushed). It is that flush that forces inserts that can cause identity to be assigned (if not using preallocation sequence strategies that can do it on the persist call itself).

Comment: @Chris I think I understand the whole lifecycle, but I somehow over years lost (at least) this one thing. Thanks, I think you found the root case. That being me assuming, that merge is side-effect function. Persist returns void, thus it must be side-effect function and you cannot use what is returned(since nothing is), unless I'm overlooking yet another thing. But you are correct about merge. This is totally mistake on my end, damn, I have no idea how can I messed this. This must be root cause. Thank you, will retest and update with results. But 99.999% it must be this.Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Chris so here goes 0.0001%. Alright, so my original code used actualy result of merge operation, just my simplified test code didn't. Fixing this in test code killed variant b) but threw me into bizarre case c. So not using result of merge is not the cause. — I need to create shareable minimal example. Just to ask: if merge is used(because of save method impl) to 'persist' new entity with natural id, and that id is not in db. Should there be any difference with persist? I cannot understand why orphanRemoval isn't honoured when merge is used, while it is with persist.

Comment: I can't tell from your TestClass, but I suspect a Hibernate bug. It must be merging in the new 'code1' instance, but not recording how it was merged/persisted, so not undoing this when it is referenced. Calling flush might help, or you might try later releases or other JPA providers. I don't know why it would work with persist but not merge (it should work with both), and can't run your test ATM to debug, but you might check something isn't flushing the transaction/context in the persist/merge flow that causes it to behave differently.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your time, if you happen to get to it and have any idea, would be really greatful for any hint. Yes, flush after merge will help, I found that already, but that still leaves spring save method unusable. But it might be hint that this is correct direction, I don't know.  I'm still reading trace log, checking code / comparing state for both flows, but no progress. It seems, that while collection is managed, the deletion listener(DefaultDeleteEventListener) isn't hit when entity is merged into persistence context. Need to debug deeper to find out when/why it is (not) called.

Comment: I'd say it is a bug and file it against Hibernate if there isn't one open already. It seems it is recording the entity reference differently when using persist vs merge, and correctly figuring the unreferenced entity should just no longer be inserted and is so unmanaged. This functionality must be missing from the merge api. This situation also occurs when there are other references in a complex object graph, but that isn't the case here. DefaultDeleteEventListener shouldn't be called on a new entity - there is nothing to delete, until after a flush/commit

Comment: @Chris then maybe there are two bugs then ;) Even though there isn't any flush, only tx commit in persist flow the item1 will be inserted and then immediately deleted. DefaultDeleteEventListener is hit, and datasource proxy also logs both statements. Or there is some other issue causing all of this. But I'm really not aware of it. Anyways, I'll try to fill those bug reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was identified as a bug in hibernate, it was fixed already, fixed should be part of 6.0.0 version. For more info:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15098